# Wordpress Post Format Link echo Url Link

Tags: wordpress

[image]

So I have this wordpress post with  `POST FORMAT  LINK`, I want to echo the `Link Url` Below which is the `Hello`. What I tried so far is

```
echo get_post_link()
echo get_the_content()
```

But its not working, please help.

Answer (score 0):

Please try `get_the_permalink()` instead. You can read more [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_permalink/)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have created meta field?